# Pl Sql exception handling

Tags: plsql

I've recently learned about exceptions and I tried to ignore some exceptions. Basically, I want to insert a certain number of rows into a new table and I'm doing it with a while. Sometimes, a duplicate ID might be inserted and so, I get the error DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX. I am throwing it but I want the code to keep on going . I've tried with NULL but it doesn't work sadly. I am using sql developer. The code is something like this :

```
 while nr <= nr_rows
 loop
 insert_into_table_code;
 end loop;

 exception
  when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
   nr:=nr-1;
   NULL;
```

This doesn't work though...it still stops the execution of the code. Any other ways I might keep going ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the exception within the loop rather than outside the loop. Pseudo code:

```
while nr <= nr_rows
loop
    begin
        insert_into_table_code;
    exception
       when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
           nr:=nr-1;
    end;
end loop;
```